# Can not acces tsconfig paths in project

Tags: typescript, alias, tsconfig

I'm trying to do include path in ts file tried may solutions available on stackoverflow but none works for me
tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./app",
    "paths": {
      "@redux/*": ["redux/*"]
    },
    "include": [
      "./app/redux/**/*", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  },
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base"
}
```

tsconfig.base.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Expo",

  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["DOM", "ESNext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "ESNext"
  },

  "exclude": ["node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"]
}
```

trying to import in app.tsx

```
import  {} from '@redux/store';// err Cannot find module '@redux/store' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

please suggest a solution (using in react app).
have also tried for other paths like components.

structure - <root>/app/components
<root>/app/redux/store.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Your paths are looking good.

You may need to use a tool like [tsconfig-paths](http://%20https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) to resolve these path names.

You can then add something like the following in your package.json file where the build is executed.

```
ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src/app.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved after adding alias in babel.config.js to project.
[read this](https://www.novis.co/post/custom-aliases-in-react-native-with-babel/)

Comment: While you are welcome to answer your own question, such answers (like all other answers) need to be up to the standards of the site. This is a link-only answer, and those are not permitted because links go dead. Please include enough of the material from the link (with proper attribution) that even if it goes dead this will still be a valuable answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using expo, make sure that in your `app.json`, under `experiments`, add

```
"tsconfigPaths": true
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).